# get a div position on leaving the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to get the position of divs when the user leaves the browser and store them in local storage, it is working fine when I refresh the page, but when I close the browser or tab it will store the position as zeros!, I couldn't figure it out, below is the code im using, appreciate to have a look,

EDIT:just tried now and it seems that it is working if I close the whole browser, but when closing only the tab it is giving zeros, any ideas?

```
window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = function () {
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var localVariable = localStorage.key(i);
    if (localVariable.substring(0, 3) == 'box') {
        var label = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localVariable)).label;
        var boxRealId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localVariable)).boxId;
        var positionTop = $('#flowchartWindow' + boxRealId).position().top;
        var positionLeft = $('#flowchartWindow' + boxRealId).position().left;
        var positionAppId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localVariable)).appId;
        localStorage.removeItem(localVariable);
        localStorage.setItem('box-app ' + positionAppId + '-box' + boxRealId, JSON.stringify({
            appId: positionAppId,
            boxId: boxRealId,
            label: label,
            positionTop: positionTop,
            positionLeft: positionLeft,
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `cookies` to store this informations

Comment: I think @TheGr8_Nik is right, when you close the page, no JS variables value will last. It means you have to store it somewhere and cookies might be a good option.

Comment: @Apolo & TheGr8_Nik Do you guys know, what [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) actually is?

Comment: Theres a chance your page will unload and all of your script will not be able to access the full dom on this event.. way to stop it is to use an alert or confirm...

Comment: localStorage is not a JS variable, it does the same work like cookies but better!

Comment: @Teemu - Sorry, you has right I never heard it before and I assumed that was a JS variable

Comment: @Teemu never heard about it, good to know !